# Restructuring XML using Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, xslt, xpath, xml-parsing

I'm brand new to Powershell, and it's all my employer uses for scripting. I need to pull information from one XML file that uses nodes, attributes, and elements that are different from the desired format.

I just need certain pieces from the original document, but I have to rename and structure the new XML to fit the formatting of the program it is being input into. What are some straight forward ways to accomplish this?

More specifically, how would I pull out say a specific root node, and then just a few attributes, subnodes, and elements, and then rename them to be compiled in the new XML?

Edit: I will try to add some vague code for you all to work with, but unfortunately, I can't give detail.

Comment: "Straight-forward" lies in the eye of the beholder. The most appropriate tool for converting XML from one format into another is XSLT. You can use XSLT from PowerShell, this is not really an issue. The more complex part would be to write the XSLT program that does the transformation. At the very least, add the input and desired output XML to your question.

Comment: It would help greatly if you were to post some code that you've already tried, and also a small but complete example of your input XML and your desired output XML.

Comment: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/XSLTWithPowershell.aspx